# prepare function sql safe method

Tags: query, sql, wpdb

I have a curious question about sql injection attack using **$wpdb->prepare** functions usages. ***https://codex.wordpress.org/Class_Reference/wpdb#Placeholders*** this link say prepare method is better to protect sql injection. So I use below code with prepare.

```
    $query = $new_wpdb->prepare(
    "INSERT INTO sym_data
    ( user_id, country, dob, height, weight, bmi )
    VALUES ( %d, %s, %s, %d, %d, %f)",
    $user_id, $country, $dob, $height, $weight, $bmi
);


$new_wpdb->query($query);
```

***Check below code***

```
    $new_wpdb->insert(
    'sym_data',
    array(
        'user_id' => $user_id,
        'country' => $country,
        'dob' => $dob,
        'height' => $height,
        'weight' => $weight,
        'bmi' => $bmi,

    ),
    array(
        '%d',
        '%s',
        '%s',
        '%d',
        '%d',
        '%0.6f'
    )
);
```

I would like to know what differences is between these code blocks. Results are the same.

**First code block is with prepare method**

**Second one is with placeholder**

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Both methods are okay (`$new_wpdb->insert` actually uses `$new_wpdb->prepare`) and provide the same level of safety when it comes to SQL escaping.

`$new_wpdb->insert` is the preferred method unless you're writing your own custom SQL query.

Comment: @por sure! Please accept my answer if you're satisfied with my response. :-)